# Prepare String Date for MySQL Insert with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

Given a date as a string like 'October 12, 2010'?

Should there be some Date "type" I should be converting to. Or is it just a matter of converting it to another string formatted as '2010-10-12' If so, what is the simplest way to convert to the yyyy-mm-dd format given my starting format?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, DATE fields in MySQL just need to be a string in the correct format.  To convert your date to the right format, use [`date`](http://php.net/date) combined with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime).

```
$date = 'October 12, 2010';
$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)); // 2010-10-12
```

Note: `'Y-m-d'` is for a DATE field, if you're using DATETIME, use `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = new DateTime('October 12, 2010');
$sqldate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

DateTime is PHP 5 >= 5.2.0

You could also use `strtotime()` however that tends to break if you want to use a date in the far future (on 32b systems).